# How to find how many decimal places there are in a column using a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe that contains a column with different amount of decimal places. I want to create something like Decimal Places in my example. The goal of this column is to count

```
df
ColA   ColB   DecimalPlaces 
A      .03    2
B      .003   3
C      10.01  2
D      11.1   1
```

I tried Below but I can't get it to work for a whole column on a dataframe

```
d = decimal.Decimal('56.43256436')

d.as_tuple().exponent
```

Comment: I tried looking at this using the decimal library, but ran into issues. you can do `df['ColB'].transform(decimal.Decimal)`, and that will return a series with all the numbers turned to decimals. However, when I did it, I got some bad float-to-decimal conversions: for example, `.03` returned `0.02999999999999999888977697537484345957636833...`, which is useless when you are trying to figure out how many places the original number had. The string solutions below seem to work better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way to do it

split the number at decimal, then take its length

```
df['decimals']=df['ColB'].astype('str').str.split('.', expand=True)[1].apply(lambda x: len(x))
df
```

```
    ColA    ColB    DecimalPlaces   decimals
0      A    0.030               2      2
1      B    0.003               3      3
2      C    10.010              2      2
3      D    11.100              1      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df['ColB'].astype(str).str.extract(r'\.(.*)', expand=False).str.len()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got basically the same as Naveed here, but, well, slightly different:

```py
df['decimals'] = df['ColB'].map(lambda x: str(x).split('.')[1]).apply(len)
```

no idea what's faster / more efficient.